# How is typing "name at example dot com" safer than "name@example.com"?

Tags: spam

Say I want to type my email address in a forum...say, `hank.chief123@gmail.com`. Obviously, that's a bad idea since spam bots will likely find it. So, I would just "cleverly" type `hank dot chief one two three at gmail dot com` or something similar.

However, wouldn't most of the spammers know this trick, and design their bots to look for `at` replacing `@`, and `dot` replacing `.`?

My question is, **How much more safe is using `at` and `dot`, and do many spam bots already try to detect those?**

Answer (score 3):

The problem for the bot creator is trying to parse all the text to identify what is an obfuscated email. It's obvious to a human by reading the context, but a script is not going to have contextual awareness. However, the regex to parse a proper email address syntax is well-known.

Try to program a bot to identify `hank dot chief one two three at gmail dot com` in your post (without knowing the email to look for). There is not a lot there for a script to use to figure out an email.

Sure, a script could look for `at [\c] dot com`, but getting the name right will be quite a chore.

Some bots will be able to programmatically identify the context based on the form used, but that requires that the forum have an identifiable format to be able to say that "the text in this area is likely an email".

Comment: And it could be much worse than that. I know someone who registered the domain dotat.at, and has email address dotat.atdot@dotat.at, which would be written out as “dotat dot atdot at dotat dot at”.

Comment: @MikeScott absolutely. but for most bots, they will be looking for the big email providers (gmail, hotmail, outlook, yahoo) which are easier to parse.

Comment: Couldn’t they just do ` at ` → `@` and etc?